# How to disable modal animations in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm running my Ionic app on an older system that doesn't handle animations that well, so I'm trying to disable them.

I've tried setting `opts` when creating modal to:

```
{
    cssClass: 'plain-modal',
    enableBackdropDismiss: false,
    enterAnimation: 'no-animation',
    leaveAnimation: 'no-animation',
    showBackdrop: true
}
```

and it seems that `no-animation` has no effect here. It is literally not applied to any DOM element. *Or is it?*

While diagnosing I've noticed that Ionic applies inline CSS to `.content` when modal is about to be opened or closed:

```
transform: translateX(100%);
will-change: transform, -webkit-transform;
transition-duration: 500ms;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.66, 0.04, 1);
```

so I tried overriding those using `initial !important`:

```
.show-page.plain-modal {
    > ion-backdrop {
        opacity: 0.5; // Nothing is displayed if I don't do this
    }

    > .modal-wrapper {
        opacity: 1; // Again nothing is displayed if I don't do this

        > .ion-page {
            > .content {
                // Override Ionic animation styles
                transform: initial !important;
                will-change: initial !important;
                transition-duration: initial !important;
                transition-timing-function: initial !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the modal shows up without any animations. A problem rises - when closing the modal using `viewController.dismiss()` nothing happens. Repeatedly clicking on the close button however does close the modal. **Why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to disable all the animations then:

*app.module.ts*

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { animate: false })
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Did anybody know a solution for only one modal ? I want to disable the animation during the modal show. Thanks

Comment: Can I disable animation only when modal is dismiss?

Comment: This not do anything

Answer (score 2):

For disabling animations on a specific modal **(Ionic 3)**:

**enterAnimation**

```
this.modalCtrl.create(MyModal).present({ animate: false });
```

**leaveAnimation**

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss(null, null, { animate: false });
```

Comment: In Ionic 5/6, it would be {animated: false}